# Direct communication from a user

Tags: support, stack-overflow, contact

I just had my daily email from Stack Overflow, and there seems to be a question that a user has asked me directly about one of my posts - it's not shown on the Stack Overflow page as a comment or reply, and I can't see any way of replying to him

however, I'm sure he hasn't found out my email address and emailed me directly because it has appeared in the same daily email from Stack Overflow with other comments

Anyone know how this works?

Comment: Deleted comment?

Answer (score 9):

Most likely it was an inappropriate comment / answer, which someone later flagged and was removed by a moderator.